Efficiently uploading/hosting chrome profile data so it can be accessed by docker image
I am total newbie when it comes to these things so this question might be dumb, but is there a way I can store somewhere efficiently my chrome profile data from my PC which is located in AppData/Local/Chrome/User Data..?
I have a app deployed thru docker image hosted on ECR AWS. The app performs some snapchat acceptance of invatation and in order to skip the login, because of the latest captcha implementation, I decided to use a already logged in session of my browser in chrome. Locally it works like a charm, but deployed is a bit trickier as the file is a bit bigger around 900mb.
Is there a way where I can upload this or host it so my docker can copy those files and build it in image?
Here is a short snippet of how I would like to have it:
class HeadlessBrowser():
    def __init__(self, user_creds, invatation_url):
        # Set up headless browser options
        chrome_options = ChromeOptions()

        #chrome_options.add_argument("--headless=new")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-tools")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--no-zygote")
        #profile_path = "C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/" #this local path
        profile_path = "/root/.config/google-chrome/" #And this one would be after docker builds the image
        chrome_options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={profile_path}")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Profile 1")
       
        chrome_options.add_argument("--verbose")
        chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
        chrome_options.add_argument("--log-path=/tmp")
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)

Basically I tried storing it on S3 but since we have some limitations the data is too big, around 900mb as I mentioned.
Then I tried perhaps commiting it on github so Docker can access it like that:
#Copy the chrome profile for session
COPY ./chrome-profile/ /root/.config/google-chrome

But it throws an error for commit.
Is there any possible solution or method that can help with this?
Any feedback or information is appreciated!
